# How do I send response object from my get request to the front end with Express and Axios?

Tags: express, mongoose, routes, axios, mern

I am trying to pull data from MongoDB to populate some timers in this app I'm building. However, I can't seem to send my response to the front end with Axios. Here is my route on the backend:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const TimerModel = require('../models/Timer');

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const timers = await TimerModel.find({});
    console.log('Succesful get req', timers);
    res.send(timers);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

My `console.log` in the try statement prints the correct data but I'm having issues with sending it to the front end. Here is the component:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Timer from '../Timer/Timer';
import axios from 'axios';

import './Wrapper.css';

function Wrapper() {

  //State effects

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('/')
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setTitle(event.target.value);
  };

  const addTimer = () => {
    const timer = <Timer title={title}     key={timers.length} />;
    let allTimers = timers.slice();
    allTimers.push(timer);
    setTimers(allTimers);
    setTitle('');
  };

  return (
  
  //JSX Code
  
  );
}

export default Wrapper;
```

In the `axios` call I make, I get this weird object when I run `console.log(res)` and I get my `index.html` for the `res.data`. Why don't I have access to the timers object I made with my backend request? Isn't it being sent when I run the command `res.send(timers)` in my route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your API url in axios request. Currently, axios is taking url of your React website that is why your response have index.html file of React website.

```
useEffect(() => {
axios
  .get('api_url/')
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the result in a state like

``````````````
`````````````
`````````````
const [time, setTimer] = useState(null)
useEffect(() => {
axios.get('/').then(res => setTimer(res.data)
}, [])
`````````````
`````````````
``````````````

and then use time vairable where you want